# Preciso que a minha função em php seja recursiva

Tags: php, array, recursão

Preciso que esta função seja recursiva, sou iniciante em php e não estou entender bem com posso fazer isso. :/

```
<?php

    function mostraArray() {

        $cena=array($_REQUEST["numeroa"], $_REQUEST["numerob"], $_REQUEST["numeroc"], $_REQUEST["numerod"], $_REQUEST["numeroe"]);

        for ($i=0; $i<=count($cena)-1; $i++) {
            return $cena[$i];
            if ($i<4){
                return ", ";
            }
        }
    }

    function ordenaArray() {

        $cena=array($_REQUEST["numeroa"], $_REQUEST["numerob"], $_REQUEST["numeroc"], $_REQUEST["numerod"], $_REQUEST["numeroe"]);
        rsort($cena);

        for ($i=0; $i<=count($cena)-1; $i++) {
            return $cena[$i];
            if ($i<4){
                return ", ";
            }
        }
    }

    echo "<p align=\"center\">Números pela <u>ordem de saída</u>: ".mostraArray()."</p>";
    echo "<p align=\"center\">Números pela <u>ordem decrescente</u>: ".ordenaArray()."</p>"
?>
```

**obs: É para a aula de php, é esse o exercício**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: As duas funções precisam ser recursivas? tem algum motivo?

Comment: @rray 
É para a aula de php, é esse o exercício: 
http://imgur.com/BWxgj6Z

Comment: Usando apenas isso consegue resolver: `$arr = array(5, 1, 25, 12, 3);` e `arsort($arr);`.

Comment: Mas é preciso que seja com função recursiva.. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A única forma que encontrei de fazer algo recursivo foi essa:

```
<?php

    function mostraArray($array) 
    {
        $string = '';
        foreach($array as $value) {
            $string .= "{$value}, ";        
        }        
        return mb_substr($string, 0, -2);
    }

    function ordenaArray($array, $e = 0) 
    {
        for($j = $e + 1; $j < count($array); $j++) {
            if(isset($array[$j]) and $array[$e] < $array[$j]) {
                $tmp = $array[$e];
                $array[$e] = $array[$j];
                $array[$j] = $tmp;
            }
        }

        if($e < count($array) - 1)
            $array = ordenaArray($array, $e + 1);

        return $array;
    }

    echo "<p align='center'>Números pela <u>ordem de saída</u>: ".mostraArray([5,1,25,12,3])."</p>";
    echo "<p align='center'>Números pela <u>ordem decrescente</u>: ".mostraArray(ordenaArray([5,1,25,12,3]))."</p>"
?>
```

O `mostraArray()` deixei mais simples, e `ordenaArra`y foi onde usei a recursividade, ela funciona como um `for`, é chamada X vezes, onde X é o tamanho do vetor, em cada uma dessa vez, pega o elemento da vez e compara com todos a sua frente, quando encontrar um maior que ele ele trocará de posição com o mesmo, fazer uma técnina chamada *insertion sort*. No fim ele pega o último resultado e retorna como resultado, assim eu chamo o método `mostraArray()` com o `array` resultante.

O fluxo de organização seria mais ou menos assim:

```
[5,1,25,12,3]
[1,25,5,12,3]
[25,1,5,12,3]
[25,1,5,12,3]
[25,5,1,12,3]
[25,1,12,5,3]
[25,12,1,5,3]
[25,12,5,1,3]
[25,12,5,3,1]
```

Observe o método usado.

Answer (score 0):

Era assim a maneira mais fácil e optimizada de resolver o exercício mas obrigado a todos ajudou a compreender as funções recursivas.

```
<?php
    $cena=array($_REQUEST["numeroa"], $_REQUEST["numerob"], $_REQUEST["numeroc"], $_REQUEST["numerod"], $_REQUEST["numeroe"]);

    function mostraArray($cena) {
        for ($i=0; $i<count($cena); $i++) {
            echo $cena[$i];
            if ($i<4) {
                echo ", ";
            }
        }
    }

    function ordenaArray($cena) {
        rsort($cena);
        return $cena;
    }

    echo "<p align=\"center\">Números pela <u>ordem de saída</u>: ".mostraArray($cena)."</p>";
    echo "<p align=\"center\">Números pela <u>ordem decrescente</u>: ".mostraArray(ordenaArray($cena))."</p>"
?>
```